# Error using diary

Tags: org-agenda, diary

Currently I try to use `diary`, but unfortunately there seems to be an error or bug in emacs.

Every time I try to create a note in `diary` through the `calendar` and then push key `i` (insert as described in the documentation), I get the following error:

```
command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, org-agenda-diary-entry
```

I am on Emacs 27.1/ Fedora 33.

Has anyone had this issue?

I read (emacs help-list) about a renaming of functions in org-mode not synced with emacs, but I don't understand this, because I'm not a developer.

Comment: With the cursor in the calendar on some date, what does `C-h c i` report? BTW, that invoke the help system and emacs and asks about the binding of the `i` key. It will probably say `org-agenda-diary-entry` and if so, see what `C-h f org-agenda-diary-entry RET` gives you and edit your question to add this information.

Comment: C-h c i reports i runs the command org-agenda-diary-entry.C-h f org-agenda-diary reports no matches. I run the command also on emacs 28, but without no luck.

Comment: "C-h f org-agenda-diary reports no matches":  did you forget to type the `-entry` part? Can you try again with `C-h f org-agenda-diary-entry RET`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. C-h f org-agenda-diary-entry RET reports no matches.

Comment: Then you have not loaded Org mode: try evaluating `(require 'org-agenda)` and then see if it works. You can then add this form to your init file, so when you restart emacs, the function will be available.

Comment: Yes that was the fault. I insert an autoload command before loading the calendar. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Comment by NickD: "Then you have not loaded Org mode: try evaluating `(require 'org-agenda)` and then see if it works. You can then add this form to your init file, so when you restart emacs, the function will be available."

Yes that was the fault. I insert an autoload command before loading the calendar. Now it works.